# How to get Python to pick a random word

Tags: python

I'm a bit stuck on how I would get python to have it pick a random word.
The user will have 5 chances after that it should display the correct word.

I'm getting this as an error

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'

```
    from random import * 


word = ['hello','bye','who','what','when','mouse','juice','phone','touch','pen','book','bag','table','pencil','day','paint','screen','floor','house','roof' ]

print("You will have 5 chances to guess the correct word! ")
rounds = 5

word = random.choice(WORDS)

correct = word
length = len(word)
length = str(length)

while tries < 5:
    guess = raw_input("The word is " + length + " letters long. Guess a letter!: ")
    if guess not in word: 
        print ("Sorry, try again.")
    else:
        print ("Good job! Guess another!")

    tries += 1

final = raw_input ("Try to guess the word!: ")

if final == correct:
    print ("Amazing! My word was ", word, "!")

else:
    print("the value to guess was ",word,"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this depends on how the words are stored in that file, but assuming that the words are separated by whitespace, it's easy:

```
with open("wordguessing.txt") as infile:
    wordlist = infile.read().split()
toguess = choice(wordlist)  # random.choice() chooses an item from a given iterable
```

Comment: Sorry I read my assignment wrong I had to have it within the file but now I'm getting an error AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'choice'

Comment: @TheBeginning First, you should bot be importing like ``from random import *`` and when you do that you should just call ``choice()``. The better way to do that is to use ``import random`` and then ``random.choice()``.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use random.choice instead random.randint. The second function will return a number between 0 and the len the list and not a word.

I rewrite your code just to show random.choice. There are more things to improve :)

```
import random 
myList =['hello','bye','who','what','when','mouse','juice','phone','touch','pen','book','bag','table','pencil','day','paint','screen','floor','house','roof' ]

print("You will have 5 chances to guess the correct word! ")
rounds = 5
word = random.choice(myList)
toguess = (input("Enter word here: "))
if word == toguess:
    print("Amazing! You guessed it!")
else:
    print("Try again!")
print("the value to guess was ",word,"\n")
```